# Survival analysis in R, using coxph to predict number of events in a given time

Tags: r, predictive-models, survival, hazard

I have been following some documentation/tutorials on Survival analysis in R. In particular https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf. I require a slight modification to a method in this tutorial. In section 3.1 they analyse repeated events in Children with chronic granulomatous disease using the CDG dataset. They fit an Andersen-Gill model as follows:

```
cfit2 <- coxph(Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~ treat + 
                 inherit + age + strata(hos.cat), data=cgd)
```

and then predict survival and cumulative hazard curves for 4 hypothetical subjects on a grid as follows:

```
dummy <- expand.grid(age=c(6,12), inherit='X-linked', 
                       treat=levels(cgd$treat))
csurv <- survfit(cfit2, newdata=dummy)
```

one can then plot the survival or cumulative hazard vs. time as required.

I would like to do something slightly different. I would like to find the value of the cumulative hazard for a specific subject at a specific time rather than for all times. The information I require is given by the above but it is given alongside a lot of other redundant information (i.e. the cumulative hazard at all other times). How can I sidestep a prediction for all times and just generate a prediction for a specific time?

Answer (score 1):

You can get survival estimates for the 4 hypothetical subjects at specific times from your csurv object.

```
summary(csurv, time = c(1,2,3,4))
```

will give you the survival estimates at timepoint `1` `2` `3` and `4`. By calculating 1-survival you can get the cummulative hazard at timepoint `1` `2` `3` and `4`.

An *alternative* would be to get the values manually from the csurv object.

```
csurv$cumhaz[csurv$time == 1]
```

Comment: This is the method I ended up using but what I really wanted was to avoid calling `survfit` on the full `dummy` matrix. I realised that rather than creating a full matrix i.e. all variables against all other variables, I could just pass a matrix containing the parameter values of interest. An acceptable answer to this question would be to make the prediction for only the times of interest rather than sample the times of interest after the fact, which is what is done here.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, I ended up using the method given by @Rootless17b. I don't think this is the answer I was looking for (see comment) but it worked nonetheless. I recently stumbled upon Gerds et al. `riskRegression` package and in particular the `predictCox` function. I have not explored it in depth but I think this does what I wanted.

Refs:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riskRegression/riskRegression.pdf
https://github.com/tagteam/riskRegression